# Scala ScalaFX: how to deal with large set of changes of Observable*

Tags: scala, observable, scalafx

I am using a `ObservableMap` for data modeling, and want to update the whole entry. Initially the `ObservableMap` is empty, and it is filled asynchronously with lots of elements.

Now the problem is that an `onChanged` event is shot for each and every entry, which creates too many events and a bogging down of the GUI. I used `pkgs.clear() ; pkgs ++= newpkgs`.

Is there way to either only trigger one `onChanged`, either by disabling the handler temporarily, or by having an operation on the map that updates all elements but fires only afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a mechanism to disable/delay/buffer UI updates.

I don't know about other JavaFX view types, but I have experience with this using `TableView` in a similar situation. I suspect other views may be similar in this regard.

At least the `TableView` has a property called `itemsProperty`. When data in `itemsProperty` is updated using `setItems` (wrapper for `itemsProperty.set(value)`), the table tries very hard to update just the minimum slice of it self.

However, for the optimizations to work, the key is that the items must be "value objects" (`hashCode` and `equals` are deep and based on the actual data being displayed and not some random references.)

In the case of `TableView` this may require elaborate `rowFactory` and 
`cellFactory` implementations. The reason is that the data in `items` can't be "preformatted" in any way or it would spoil the optimizations inside `TableView`.

Realizing the above, solved my update churn problems. Maybe other answers can provide other tips.

Comment: I don't have a good solution, what I did now was the following: Add a dummy element to the data structure, and in the `onChange` code just execute some code when this dummy element is changed. Finally, trigger the updates manually. This way still thousands of onChange events are triggered, but they are nearly nops, and only when I trigger manually an update by changing the dummy element the real update happens. Not really optimal, but at least a solution. Of course one needs to take this dummy element into account in other areas of the GUI code :-(